# IN query is not working group_concat in mysql subquery

Tags: mysql

IN query is not working in sub_query of mysql
Please take look-:

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( text ) 
        FROM course_intersted_in_list 
        WHERE id IN ( urd.interested_course )) as interested_course_text,
       urd.* 
from user_registration_data as urd
```

Here **urd.interested_course** have values like 1,2,3,4 for some users

**user_registration_data** table is like

```
id             interested_course
 1             1,2,3,4,5
 2             1,4,5
```

**course_intersted_in_list** table is like

```
id             interested_course
 1             mbbs
 2             dental
 3             basic
```

Comment: are these `urd.interested_course` values stored as comma separated values ?

Comment: Show your table and some sample data please

Comment: Check this link...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: Its better to fix your table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `interested_course` has comma separated ids, you can use `find_in_set` to search a value in csv string:

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( text ) 
        FROM course_intersted_in_list 
        WHERE find_in_set(id, urd.interested_course)
        ) as interested_course_text,
       urd.* 
from user_registration_data urd;
```

Also, I recommend staying away from CSV data in RDBMS and normalize the data. that way you'll get a system that scales.

Comment: Its working I forget about find in set , its working now

Comment: @vipulsharma if its working read here what to do with the working answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` instead:

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( text ) 
        FROM course_intersted_in_list 
        WHERE find_in_set(id, urd.interested_course)) as interested_course_text,
       urd.* 
from user_registration_data as urd
```

`IN()` doesn't work on table columns, only against a list inside `()`